# struct error in defining struct in one header file, and using it in another

Tags: c

I have 4 Files = pic.h, main.c, framehandle.c and framehandle.h

Both pic.h and framehandle.h are included within my main:

```
#include "pic.h"
#include "framehandling.h"
```

pic.h has the following struct definition.

```
struct f
{
    unsigned sleep : 1;
    unsigned push  : 1;
    unsigned rx    : 1;
    unsigned tx    : 1;
    unsigned validPacket : 1;
};
```

I declare this struct in my main.c file using

```
struct f flag;
```

when I try to use this inside framehandle.c I get an undeclared error which I understand.

To solve this I add the following inside framehandle.h:

```
extern struct f flag;
```

However the compiler is still complaining that flags are not declared inside framehandle.c

What am i doing wrong? 
wouldn't extern struct f flag; supposed to tell the compiler to look else where for the decleration? 
wouldnt't placing this inside the subjects header be the correct place?

--Edit--

I am adding the sequence of my include files and my variable declerations

```
#include "pic.h"
#include "framehandling.h"

struct f flag;

void main(void)
{ }
```

Comment: Does framehandle.c include pic.h? What is the exact compiler error?

Comment: framehandle.c does include pic.h. The exact compiler error is #framehandling.c:97: error: 'flag' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: Silly question maybe, but does `framehandle.c` include `framehandle.h`?

Comment: @BryanOlivier yes it does Bryan

Comment: Then try to look at the preprocessor output (option `-E` for `gcc`) of `framehandle.c` and see if it indeed contains the `extern struct f flag` declaration. Your `main.c` mentions `framehandling.h` whereas the remainder of your text mentions `framehandle.h`.

Comment: and check your header fenceposts.

Comment: The solution to the problem was that extern struct f flag should have been inside pic.h. It makes sense in a way, to place it right after the decleration.. 

I would also like to thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem was that extern struct f flag should have been inside pic.h. It makes sense in a way, to place it right after the decleration.. I would also like to thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on if you have declared `struct f flag;` in main.c as global or local.  If you have it declared inside of the function, you will have to move the declaration outside the function.

Comment: Struct f flag is declared as global

Comment: @Volcano Is it declared before the place where it's used or after?

Comment: I just realized that you are adding the extern definition inside the header file.  Can you move the extern to your C source and check the error?  Also, which compiler do you use?  If it is gcc, you can check with the -E option to see how your preprocessor includes the definitions.

Comment: I think it is after? I am not sure, I will edit my question to include my #includes and variable decleration.

Comment: @unxnut placing it in the C files gives a useless variable decleration error

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Did you put it in framehandle.c?  Because that is where it was complaining earlier.  Can you also try by changing the variable name to something else?